# Format date Excel in Spanish with first capital letter Pivot Table

Tags: excel, vba, format, pivot-table

Hi i'm been trying to format a date in a Pivot Table, my default language in *Excel* is Spanish, when i try to format a Date (`25/02/2018`) i want to show only the month. I'm using this format `MMMM` but it gives me `febrero` i want to show `Febrero` instead.

I try to use something like in the `Text` Formula but i couldn't achive this. I also tried adding the Spanish format code `0C0A` but it doesn't works.

[image: Format Dialogue box]

Comment: Use `MMMM`. This is documented.

Comment: As you can see in the image i'm using that format and still showing with lower case at the beginning.

Comment: Admittedly a work around, but you could wrap `PROPER` around your `TEXT` formula.

Comment: @ReyJuna i'm not using a Cell thats why i can use `PROPER` function.

Comment: I can't see the image. Imgur is blocked by many corporate proxy servers, which is why images should be avoided wherever possible. Your text says *I'm using this format `mmmm`*, which indicates you're using lowercase `m` and not uppercase `M`. Don't shoot the messenger for responding to what you wrote specifically in your post. :-) When I use `mmmm` in Excel, it shows `january`, and when I use `MMMM` it shows `January`.

Comment: @KenWhite mmm ok, i will edit.

Comment: @KenWhite Are you sure, that mmmm works in your Excel language? In my German Excel version all m, mm, mmm, mmmm, mmmmm ... are only interpreted as minutes and even all other variants than m or mm are rejected.

Comment: @Asger: Yes. I placed `=Today()` in cell A1, chose `Format`, and set the cell format to `mmmm`, and cell A1 displayed `january`. I then changed the format to `MMMM`, and cell A1 changed to `January`. Tested before I made my initial comment to make sure I was remembering correctly. (I use US English language on Windows 10.)

Comment: @KenWhite That's really interesting. I made some checks in my German version and updated my answer with some screenshots, showing how it's handled here (German Excel 2016 on Win 10)

Answer (score 1):

## Built-In Month Name List (e. g. in Spain)

Please check in your Excel options, how the built-in list with language dependent month names is implemented by Microsoft:

Excel Opciones > Avancadas > General > Modificar listas personalizadas
Excel Options > Advanced > General > Edit Custom Lists

I guess they are written in lower cases like this:
[image: Spanish built-in list of month names]

Note: You cannot edit or delete a built-in list, says [support.office.com](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-or-delete-a-custom-list-for-sorting-and-filling-data-d1cf624f-2d2b-44fa-814b-ba213ec2fd61)

You may try to add an additional list with Proper cased month names, but the dialog will not accept it as a new list (at least in my German Excel version it doesn't).

## Number Formatting

In German Excel all different user defined format codes with an "M" or "m" work like this:

[image: Excel number formats with month name]

## VBA Format()

You may also check in VBA, if `mmmm` or `MMMM` has different results in your language:

```
Dim d As Date
d = DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), Day(Now))
Debug.Print d
Debug.Print Format(d, "M"), Format(d, "MM"), Format(d, "MMM"), _
    Format(d, "MMMM"), Format(d, "MMMMM"), Format(d, "MMMMMM")
Debug.Print Format(d, "m"), Format(d, "mm"), Format(d, "mmm"), _
    Format(d, "mmmm"), Format(d, "mmmmm"), Format(d, "mmmmmm")
```

In German Excel 2016 there is no difference between `M` or `m`:

```
27.01.2019 
1             01            Jan           Januar        Januar1       Januar01
1             01            Jan           Januar        Januar1       Januar01
```

## Additional Field

If you try a cell formula like `=PROPER(TEXT(DATE(2019,1,1),"MMMM"))` (in Spanish: `=NOMPROPIO(TEXTO(FECHA(2019,1,28), "MMMM"))`, the result is a text only and of course can not be used for further calculation.
If you add it as additional column in your datasource for the pivot table, it can be used for the filter or row value, but sorting order might be confusing!

Answer (score 0):

I know what the problem is, but unfortunately, I haven't found a workaround yet.

In Spanish and in my case, Portuguese, months are not nouns, so they are spelled all lowercase, whereas in English, German and Swedish (the ones that answered here) they are nouns and are therefore capitalized.

You can look this up in dictionaries, or in Google Translate, if you write "Enero" in Spanish and translate it to English you get "Enero"<->"January". If you translate it back, you get "January"<->"enero". So despite you first putting in "Enero" capitalized, when its translated back, it shows it the correct way which is "enero". Same happens with German an Portuguese "Januar"<->"janeiro" etc.

Regarding mmmm and MMMM, it makes no diference, they are all the same. Capital Ms are the same as lowercase ms and don't do anything to the capitalization of the months.

Only thing you can do is use the short form "mmm" which will give you "Ene", "Feb" capitalized, but that's only a bad workaround.

Comment: Small clarification: in English, not all nouns are capitalized. "Dog" is a noun, but we say "look at that dog", not "look at that Dog". In English, nouns that must be capitalized are called "_proper_ nouns".

Answer (score -1):

For Swedish. You can replace **sv-SE** with **es-SP** (I think for spanish language )
=PROPER(TEXT(B11;"[$-sv-SE]MMMM"))

Comment: This format is for a cell on my case is a Pivot Table